# PHP area inside wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla

I have a company page developed using `Joomla`, and inside it, an administrative area developed in PHP. Only users with certain privileges, `partner` and `partner_employees`, can access this area.

I need to migrate the front site to `Wordpress`, and keep the same behaviour on restricted area, using the login from `Wordpress`.

Is it possible?

Where should I put the directory from this restricted area?

How to put links on `Wordpress` page pointing to this area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to render the restricted area in `wp` like `My Account` developed in `PHP` and not to integrate another framework (`Joomla` in your case) with `wp`, you can simply achieve that by:

First, create a `wp template` that `includes` the restricted area logic. Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Second, create a `wp page` using the created `template` and set `link` for this page in your `menu`. Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

Now if you wish to handle the authentication as well with Wordpress, either you can use many available plugins out there, e.g.:

1. https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/
2. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpfront-user-role-editor/

Or you can custom code your own, to know more you may ref here:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Your template file may look like (as a starting point):

```
 <?php
/**
 * Template Name: My Account Page Temp
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can( $capability ) ): ?>

 //render your restricted area content          

<?php else : ?>

// Redirect him for login

<?php endif; ?>
```

> Note: You can break your restricted area logic in many nested
>   `template parts` and can use them within your `main template` as per
>   requirements. Put them under your active theme directory:
>   `wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/myaccount`

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'featured-content' ); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hint: `else:` - than - `endif;`